# Initial database table creation for AWS Lambda and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

How would one go about creating the initial tables *before* a lambda function attempts to perform any database operations?

My thinking is that once, for example, a CloudFormation template finishes and creates a stack, execute an auxiliary lambda function that creates the initial tables.

I'm coming from developing in Node.js/Express and am trying to adjust serverless architecture. Usually I would just initialize tables in the main `app.js` file, but unsure how to do that here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you are looking at initial table creation for database for your application, additionally there are several things to consider.

- How to initialize the database tables and running the seed data.
- How to run this to different databases (Multiple environments for Test, Dev & etc.).
- How to do the change management of scripts/configuration and executing the changes.
- How do you revert a change for rollback.
- How to do DevOps (Integrate with CI/CD).

Considering these facts, it is important to keep these changes version controlled with required tooling and Frameworks for Migrations, Seeding, Rollback & etc. would be advantages.

You can trigger this after the creation of CloudFormation Stack, using SNS topic, to trigger CI/CD Tools & Pipeline (E.g Using Jenkins) to execute the initial table creations and also to make subsequent changes and seeding to the tables in an autonomous way.

If you are using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) with Lambda for your application, you can use the [Serverless-Dynamodb-Local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-local) Plugin to help you with Seeding, Migrations & etc. (We developed it also to address this issue)

Comment: Not only is this not an answer, but it is a plug for a DynamoDB plugin whereas the OP specifically mentioned RDS not DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either serverless or server-based.

**Serverless:**

If you want to go serverless, you can write a lambda function and choose appropriate driver for your node-js function depending upon the RDS server used and run your queries. You may have to write fail-safe queries so that they are rerunnable.

Using node-js with Lambda to write your queries,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html

With CloudFormation, you can automate deployment of lambda as well.

ServerBased:

Once CloudFormation is complete, you can run shell scripts ro create appropriate tables. (Rerunnable policies may apply here too).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Serverless. Would I just manually invoke that lambda function to create the tables in the database?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Make sure you cannot exceed 5 minut s to run. If it exceeds you can pass external parameters so that you can what to run on each sun.